How to force git merge to only add one folder
I have branchA and branchB  with the different folders in each branch.
How do I merge branchB into branchA and keep the folder from both branches?
 ...----O----O----O----O----O----O----O----O=branchA
        |_folder1      |                  /|_folder1
        |_folder2      |                 / |_folder2
                       |                /  |_folder3
                       |               / 
                       `----O--------O=branchB
                            |_folder3


It mostly depends on how your branches relate to each other. The "tree" you're showing is not a tree. It's a list of folders present under each branch. The output of git log --oneline --graph branchA branchB would be a good start to understand how your branches are linked.

It's not entirely clear. Is branchA a branch or a directory or something else? Do you want to move a directory? Do you want to do a subtree merge? Something else?

The basic merge should work. If it turns out that it doesn't, you can also add a commit on branchB which explicitly adds folder1/ and folder2/ from branchA: git restore -s branchA -SW -- folder1/ folder2/; git commit before merging branchB.

@knittl Is updated question explains it better?

Judging by your new graph, it seems like your branchB is branched off branchA so why are folders 1 and 2 missing? Have they been deleted on branchB? If not, your graph is misleading and the merge should be fine, only adding folder3. Then again, all this is quite unclear, a real log graph would be clearer, if I may.

@jackhab a bit. Did branchB delete folder1 and folder2? If so, which commit deleted the folders?

@RomainValeri The branchB, indeed, deleted folder1 and folder2 and it should remain with only folder3 for its whole lifetime and this folder should be periodically merged into branchA (which never modifies it).

@jackhab And does branchA contain/modify folder3?

Okay, clearer now. Since these branches do have different structures on purpose, then they should not be merged, I guess. Consider another way to bring folder3 changes onto branchA, for example by doing some variant of git restore --source=branchB -- folder3/ then committing. If branchA never modifies the folder, nothing should be overwritten. An alternative would be to merge branchB then restore everything but folder3, but it's probably more work that way. Depending on your specifics, of course.

It seems you have grossly misunderstood branches. Every commit carries the entire project's state. If one commit removed some folders, then that is the statement "It is for the better of the entire project that these folders do not exist anymore, now and for all time". Therefore, when you merge the branch, this statement is applied to the merge result. If the statement is not correct, then you must not remove the folders.

@RomainValeri Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Please, post your comment as answer so that I can tick it.

@j6t I do know this is not the proper way to keep things in git. I just needed a workaround for something that cannot be currently fixed.


Disclaimer: as j6t rightfully noted in comments above, this is not the
intended way to use branches, since each one should represent some
state of the entire project, not a part of it. The following is just a
workaround to achieve what's asked, but you probably should reconsider
your branching strategy.

That being said, you can bring your folder3's changes in your branchA branch without merging thanks to git restore (for older versions, see git checkout):
# be sure to be on your branchA, with a clean working tree, then
git restore --source=branchB -- folder3/
git add folder3
git commit "Your message"


Use git restore -WS to restore to both worktree and stage aka index,  so no git add needed later, and to record it as a merge git merge --no-commit -s ours branchB first to set up the ancestry and leave the actual merging for you, to commit after (as always) setting up the exact results you want.
